# How can I limit the applications a user can access?

Tags: macos, applications

My brother is using my computer tomorrow and he just needs zoom, how do I force zoom to the foreground until I enter a password? I am not good with apple script, so if you could make it so I can just use it that would be good. I am on a school computer so I do not have admin rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don‘t need Applescript for this.

- Open System Preferences
- Create a new *standard* or *Managed with Parental Controls* user account for your brother
- Enable Parental Control on this account
- Limit access to the applications you want him to use

Comment: I am on a school computer, I do not have admin rights

Comment: You're a little stuck then. In order to set up something like this, you inherently need greater abilities than the other person using the computer—think about it, otherwise either (A) your brother would also be able to disable Zoom, or (B) you'd be stuck with Zoom only forever. And if you don't have admin rights, you can't limit someone else's rights.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Automator app that opens zoom and if every second it tells it to open, it keeps it open. 
[image]

Comment: How do you prevent your brother from using Cmd-Tab, Cmd-Space or the Dock?

Comment: every second it tells zoom to open and hide anything else.

Comment: I can also disable Cmd-Space and Cmd-Tab via settings and just turn them on again at the end